# What does it mean by "make it all"

Tags: meaning

For example,

> **This has made it all the more necessary for us to convey that method.**

I saw the translation was "consequently, we should insist on conveying that method" in another language, but why it was changed into "made it all the more necessary"?
What's the meaning of "all"?
It really puzzled me.

Comment: Sorry, but what translation? [Why **was it** changed to etc.]

Comment: 'This has made it necessary for us to convey that method.' ~ 'This has made it even more necessary for us to convey that method.' = 'This has made it all the more necessary for us to convey that method.' The last two seem illogical ('necessary' is absolute) but are acceptable, idiomatic, having a pragmatic implication (emphasis).

Comment: They have voted to close, but here are some clues for you: make it necessary to [do something]. It is a dummy pronoun. alll the more= even more.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "all the more" is confusing part.  "all the more" means "even more".  From Merriam-Webster

> **all the more**: even more
>
> > The fact that they'd written the play themselves made it all the more impressive.

"Much more" would be another alternate.

If you substitute "even more" and "much more" into your example for "all the more" you get:

- > This has made it **even more** necessary for us to convey that method.
- > This has made it **much more** necessary for us to convey that method.